# Problems with function template and type_traits

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, type-deduction

I have a function "has_holes", which shall calculate something based on a mask. The number of bits is determined by the type of "mask". Therefore I want to use a template. Furthermore, I only want to allow instantiations of has_holes which take parameters by value. So I added a typetrait "remove_all_t" which gives the underlying type. But when I do so, I cant build it any more getting the error:

"error: no matching function for call to 'has_holes(unsigned int&)"
note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'BASE_TYPE'

However, if I explicitly call the funktion instantiation "has_holes it works.
Did I mess up template instantiation and type deduction rules? Or where is my mistake?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>
#include <experimental/type_traits>


//removes everything except arrays []
template<class T> struct remove_all { typedef T type; };
template<class T> struct remove_all<T*> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class T> struct remove_all<T&> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class T> struct remove_all<T&&> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class T> struct remove_all<T const> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class T> struct remove_all<T volatile> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class T> struct remove_all<T const volatile> : remove_all<T> {};
template<class T>
using remove_all_t = typename remove_all<T>::type;

template<typename BASE_TYPE, class = typename std::enable_if_t<std::experimental::is_unsigned_v<BASE_TYPE>, BASE_TYPE>>
bool has_holes(remove_all_t<BASE_TYPE> mask){ //remove "remove_all_t<>" and it will work

    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() > std::numeric_limits<decltype(mask) >::digits, "Base_type has to much digits max_digits=std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()");
    for (unsigned int  pos{1}; pos<std::numeric_limits<decltype(mask)>::digits; ++pos ){
        ;//algorithm will be placed here, not implemented yet
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int mask = 0b00110011;
    auto result = has_holes<unsigned int>(mask); //works
    auto result2 = has_holes(mask);//error: no matching function for call to 'has_holes(unsigned int&)'|
    std::cout<<result<<" ..."<<result2<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Best regards,
Hendrik

Comment: There should have been more to your error message like *candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'BASE_TYPE'*.  There is no way for the compiler to deduce what you want `BASE_TYPE` to be.

Comment: I use gcc with Codeblocks, where there is not shown the complete output. I know that there is an option to enable fullouput, but I could not find it yet.

Comment: Trying compiling with clang gives following error:   //error: no matching function for call to 'has_holes(unsigned int&)'|
note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'BASE_TYPE'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ template deduction is not unlimited.  It will refuse to attempt to invert possibly Turing-complete processes.

The C++ standard calls this a non-deduced context: a context in which template arguments will not be deduced.

`remove_all_t<BASE_TYPE>` induces a non-deduced context.  Because when you map a type through a template like `remove_all_t<X>` *in theory* the mapping process could be Turing complete.

And in general, template type maps do not tell C++ how to invert them.  The standard tells compilers not to try.

Remove `remove_all_t<BASE_TYPE>` and replace with `BASE_TYPE` and it will be deduced as a value, always.

If you are afraid someone will pass `int&` explicitly as a template type parameter, add a `static_assert( std::is_same<remove_all_t<BASE_TYPE>, BASE_TYPE>::value, "values only");` to the body of the function.

Comment: Your workaround is simple and works :) But I don't understand the problem you describe. Why is my mapping a bad idea and stl does it with all its typetraits? And what do you mean wirh "->invert<- possible turing completness"? Could you explain that further? Sorry for the questions but I am no native english speaker :-)

Comment: It isn't a bad idea.  `std` does it because that is how you transform one type to another in a type trait in C++.  These mappings do not tell the compiler how to invert them.  You are asking for a type `BASE_TYPE` such that `remove_all_t<BASE_TYPE>` matches the function argument.  This requires inverting the `remove_all_t` type mapping.  Inverting a function in a turing complete language (which includes template metaprogramming) is not possible in the general case.  So C++ states that compilers are not supposed to even try.  They call this using the template parameter in a non deduced context.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. After reading Scott Meyers "Effective Modern C++ Item 1" I realized that I don't need the "remove_all" type_trait at all. Mask's type will be an lvalue and referenceness, const and volatile will be ignored anyway. However, the static_assert is necessary for "evil users".

Comment: I think that the static_assert is not necessary neither because the enable_if statement should reject any reference and pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're concerned about the number of bits, just do the type reductions when you work out the number of bits.

```
template<typename BASE_TYPE,
         class = typename std::enable_if_t<std::experimental::is_unsigned_v<remove_all_t<BASE_TYPE> > > 
        >
bool has_holes(BASE_TYPE mask)
{
    using reduced_type = remove_all_t<BASE_TYPE>;
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() > std::numeric_limits<reduced_type>::digits,
                  "Base_type has to many digits max_digits=std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()");
    for (unsigned int pos{1};    // really start at 1 (nor 0)?
         pos < std::numeric_limits<reduced_type>::digits;
         ++pos )
    {
        //algorithm will be placed here, not implemented yet
    }
    return true;
}
```

though you presumably don't want to accept `BASE_TYPE*` (so must modify this).

Comment: Regarding the for loop: start 1 may seem strange, but is correct in this place for the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Template argument deduction **is attempted**, as described in `[temp.deduct.call]/p1`
with `P = typename remove_all<BASE_TYPE>::type` and `A = unsigned int`. Eventually `BASE_TYPE` cannot be deduced (nor defaulted) and that turns into an incomplete deduction per `[temp.deduct.type]/p2`.

As a sidenote, I would use a simple workaround (since you already have other static assertions in place)

```
template<typename BASE_TYPE, class = typename std::enable_if_t<std::experimental::is_unsigned_v<BASE_TYPE>, BASE_TYPE>, 
         typename RBASE_TYPE = remove_all_t<BASE_TYPE>>
                  ^^^^^^^^^^
bool has_holes(BASE_TYPE mask){

    // Use RBASE_TYPE here

    return true;
}
```

<kbd>[Simplified example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IbakiQhIViwGwEUT)</kbd>